# Unable to run the OpenCover against Silverlight application on 64-bit machine

Tags: silverlight, code-coverage, opencover

I am using the OpenCover code coverage tool against silverlight application , but i am getting the following exception while running please help me.

**Cmd line Argument :**

```
D:\Work\Projects\IRI\AB\APTT\APTT 2.4.8\Dev\Application>OpenCover\OpenCover.Console.exe -register:user "-target:C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" "-targetargs:http://localhost/APTT/Welcome.aspx" "-targetdir:D:\Work\Projects\IRI\AB\APTT\APTT 2.4.8\Dev\Application\IRI.PA.Web.Silve
rlight\Bin\Debug" -output:opencoverResult.xml
```

**Exception Detais :**

```
An exception occured: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Core, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e,
stack:    at Autofac.Builder.RegistrationData..ctor(Service defaultService)
   at Autofac.Builder.RegistrationBuilder`3..ctor(Service defaultService, TActivatorData activatorData, TRegistrationStyle style)
   at Autofac.RegistrationExtensions.RegisterInstance[T](ContainerBuilder builder, T instance)
   at OpenCover.Framework.Bootstrapper.Initialise(IFilter filter, ICommandLine commandLine, IPersistance persistance, IPerfCounters pe
   at OpenCover.Console.Program.Main(String[] args) in c:\Projects\opencover.git\working\main\OpenCover.Console\Program.cs:line 67
```

Thanks in Advance.

Regards,
Rakesh K

Comment: What version of OpenCover are you using?

Comment: I am using version 4.5.1923

Comment: Are the silverlight assemblies [registered in the GAC](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/silverlight/en-US/c68f4ed0-9305-4b7f-82f3-4559937c8d62/silverlight-systemcore-2050-reference-and-aspnet-systemcore-reference-3500?forum=silverlightdevtools)?

Comment: Silverlight assemblies means are you referring to System.Core?

When i have checked in GAC there was an System.Core dll with version 3.5.

Later i have added even System.Core dll (Version 2.0.5.0)in GAC.

Still facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

What you are seeing looks like this issue [Could not load file or assembly System.Core after updating to 1.6.1.1718](http://help.octopusdeploy.com/discussions/problems/8154-could-not-load-file-or-assmebly-systemcore-after-updating-to-1611718) and it also seems to be related to AutoFac.

The suggested solution is to run a MS Patch [KB2468871 - Update for the .NET Framework 4](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2468871)